# Extract either two or three words and exclude duplicates and accronyms

Tags: r, regex

I have a group of names worded in a bizarre fashion. Here is a sample:

```
Sammy WatkinsS. Watkins
Buffalo BillsBUF
New England PatriotsNE
Tre'Quan SmithT. Smith
JuJu Smith-SchusterJ. Smith-Schuster
```

My goal is to clean it so either first and last name show for names or just team names is returned for teams. Here is what have tried:

```
df$name <- sub("^(.*[a-z])[A-Z]", "\\1", "\\1", df$name)
```

This is what I'm getting returned

```
Sammy WatkinsS. Watkins
Buffalo BillsBUF
New England PatriotsNE
Tre'Quan SmithT. Smith
JuJu Smith-SchusterJ. Smith-Schuster
```

To be clear, goal would be to have this:

```
Sammy Watkins
Buffalo Bills
New England Patriots
Tre'Quan Smith
JuJu Smith-Schuster
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(name = c(
  "Sammy WatkinsS. Watkins",
  "Buffalo BillsBUF",
  "New England PatriotsNE",
  "Tre'Quan SmithT. Smith",
  "JuJu Smith-SchusterJ. Smith-Schuster"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Where is this data coming from? It probably makes sense to go back and set and see if you can more cleanly import it. What you are describing doesn't really seem like a task for a regular expression. What exactly is the pattern you want to match?

Comment: But you don't have just first/last name, you *sometimes* have a middle initial or space in either first or last ... and the way to know if it is an embedded space or a new name is subjective. I don't know that regex will be the holy grail here, you are going to need some logic and inference, I suspect.

Comment: See [this](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). It's non-trivial to do "give me the first and last names or team names".  There needs to be concrete definitions of what a name entails, and that isn't easy (see link) unless your data is predictably and concretely defined. If it is defined, please describe the constraints.

Comment: Try `df$name <- sub("[A-Z]+(?:\\.\\s+\\S+)?$", "", df$name)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/6fJXCN/2))

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/HKU9dp/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked! EXCEPT for one odd ball name that wasn't included for you: "Equanimeous St. BrownE. St. Brown". not sure why it worked with a bunch of other names with various styles but not this one but that's ok. thank you very much!

Comment: @JeffHenderson I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60299097/3832970) with a fix for this string as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
(?<=[a-z])[A-Z](?=[.\sA-Z]).*
```

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/6fJXCN/5). Without experience in `R` I'm unsure if this would be accepted. Also, there may be neater patterns as I'm rather new to RegEx.

I've also included a (possibly unlikely) sample: `Sammy J. WatkinsJ.S. Watkins`

Comment: @JeffHenderson, did this actually work for all your cases?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
df$name <- sub("\\B[A-Z]+(?:\\.\\s+\\S+)*$", "", df$name)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6fJXCN/4)

**Pattern details**

- `\B` - a non-word boundary (there must be a letter, digit or `_` right before)
- `[A-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII uppercase letters (use `\p{Lu}` to match any Unicode uppercase letters)
- `(?:\.\s+\S+)*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Two laps:

```
df$name <- gsub(".\\. .*", "", df$name)
df$name <- gsub("[A-Z]*$", "", df$name)
```

The first line removes all cases of the form "x. surname" and the second removes all capital letters at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
sub("(.*?\\s.*?[a-z](?=[A-Z])).*", "\\1", df$name,  perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "Sammy Watkins"        "Buffalo Bills"        "New England Patriots"
#> [4] "Tre'Quan Smith"       "JuJu Smith-Schuster"

sub(".*?\\s.*?[a-z](?=[A-Z])", "", df$name, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "S. Watkins"        "BUF"               "NE"               
#> [4] "T. Smith"          "J. Smith-Schuster"
```

We're splitting between a lower case character and an upper case character, but not before we see a space.

You could also use *unglue* :

```
library(unglue)
unglue_unnest(df, name, "{name1=.*?\\s.*?[a-z]}{name2=[A-Z].*?}")
#>                  name1             name2
#> 1        Sammy Watkins        S. Watkins
#> 2        Buffalo Bills               BUF
#> 3 New England Patriots                NE
#> 4       Tre'Quan Smith          T. Smith
#> 5  JuJu Smith-Schuster J. Smith-Schuster
```